# jQuery Week Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for an easy way to select an entire week (Sunday to Saturday).

Initial searching for some sort of jQuery control has turned up empty. Does anyone have any recommendations of some?

jQuery UI Themeroller enabled is a plus.

Comment: Select an entire week from what? A datepicker? if so which one.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, weeks go from Monday to Sunday. :) Keep I18N in mind!

Comment: jQuery UI's datepicker shows dates from sun to sat =\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this plugin:

- [jquery.datePicker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerSelectWeek.html): A flexible unobtrusive calendar component for jQuery

Is not the jQuery UI one, it has built in week selection.

Comment: This is the actual feature request, marked as "fixed": http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/detail?id=13

Comment: Yick, terrible UI. Must be a better one out there.